# efficient use of raster functions in r

Tags: r, gis, raster

I have 500+ points in a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` object; I have a 1.7GB (200,000 rows x 200,000 cols) `raster` object. I want to have a tabulation of the values of the raster cells within a buffer around each of the 500+ points.

I have managed to achieve that with the code below (I got a lot of inspiration [from here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130522/r-increase-speed-of-crop-mask-extract-raster-by-many-polygons).). However, it is slow to run and I would like to make it run faster. It actually runs OK for buffers with "small" widths, say 5km ro even 15km (~1 million cells), but it becomes super slow when buffer increases to say 100km (~42 million cells).

I could easily improve on the loop below by using something from the `apply` family and/or a parallel loop. But my suspicion is that it is slow because the `raster` package writes 400Mb+ temporary files for each interaction of the loop.

```
# packages
library(rgeos)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

myPoints = readOGR(points_path, 'myLayer')
myRaster = raster(raster_path)

myFunction = function(polygon_obj, raster_obj) {
    # this function return a tabulation of the values of raster cells 
    # inside a polygon (buffer)

    # crop to extent of polygon
    clip1 = crop(raster_obj, extent(polygon_obj))

    # crops to polygon edge & converts to raster
    clip2 = rasterize(polygon_obj, clip1, mask = TRUE)

    # much faster than extract
    ext = getValues(clip2) 

    # tabulates the values of the raster in the polygon
    tab = table(ext)

    return(tab)
}

# loop over the points
ids = unique(myPoints$ID)
for (id in ids) {

    # select point
    myPoint = myPoints[myPoints$ID == id, ]

    # create buffer
    myPolygon = gBuffer(spgeom = myPoint, byid = FALSE, width = myWidth)

    # extract the data I want (projections, etc are fine)
    tab = myFunction(myPolygon, myRaster)

    # do stuff with tab ...
}
```

My questions:

1. Am I right to partially blame the writing operations? If I managed to avoid all those writing operations, would this code run faster? I have access to a machine with 32GB of RAM -- so I guess it is safe to assume I could load the `raster` to the memory and need not to write temporary files?
2. What else could I do to improve efficiency in this code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should approach it like this

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
myPoints <- readOGR(points_path, 'myLayer')
myRaster <- raster(raster_path)
e <- extract(myRaster, myPoints, buffer=myWidth)
```

And then something like

```
etab <- sapply(e, table)
```

It is hard to answer your question #1 as we do not know enough about your data (we do not know how many cells are covered by a "100 km" buffer). But you can set options about when to write to file with the `rasterOptions` function. You notice that `getValues` is faster than extract, based on the post you link to, but I think that is wrong, or at least not very important. The combination of `crop`, `rasterize` and `getValues` should have a similar performance as `extract` (which does almost exactly that under the hood). If you go this route anyway, you should pass an empty RasterLayer, created by `raster(myRaster)` for faster cropping.

Comment: what info about my data is enough to answer #1?